# Rails4: How to realize multiple where conditions in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to display the data as followings;

```
Day1
09:00 Math
11:00 Science
Room classA (3rd floor)

Day2
10:00 English
13:00 Music
Room classB (1st floor)
```

sample articles table

```
school_id day start_time title
1         1   09:00      Math
1         2   10:00      English
1         1   11:00      Science
2         1   12:00      Physics
1         2   13:00      Music
```

sample rooms table

```
school_id day name    detail
1         1   classA  3rd floor
1         2   classB  1st floor
2         1   classC  2nd floor
```

I think I should realize SQL in Rails as below to display rooms data.

`SELECT name, detail FROM rooms WHERE articles.school_id = rooms.school_id AND articles.day = rooms.day`

It would be appreciated if you could give me the best way in Rails although I tried some code.

View code

```
<div class="row">
  <% @articles.each do |a| %>

      <%= a.start_time %>&nbsp;<%= a.title %><br>
      <!-- I can't display rooms.name and rooms.detail -->

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller code

```
def show
  @articles = Article.where(school_id: (params[:id])).order(day: :asc)
```

Model code

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles


class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :school


class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
    #(nothing)
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150999999999) do

  create_table "rooms", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "detail"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "school_id"
    t.integer  "day"
    t.string   "start_time"
    t.string   "end_time"
    t.integer  "category"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "contents"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "schools", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Comment: Is the relationship between a subject (e.g. math) and what room it's being taught in being stored anywhere? I see school_id in the articles table but nothing more specific than that.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @eeeeeean. There is no relationship between a subject and room. Because a room is determined by `day` not `title` (subject: math, music ...). All subjects are taught in the same room in a day. So I think I should program such as `SELECT name, detail FROM rooms WHERE articles.school_id = rooms.school_id AND articles.day = rooms.day` in SQL terms.

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample database, a room belongs to a school, and a school can have many rooms. So you would add

```
has_many :rooms
```

to the School class, and

```
belongs_to :school
```

to the Room class.

Then, to get a list of rooms for a given school, you can just use the built-in Rails methods. You might do this in a controller:

```
my_school = School.find(params[:id])
some_rooms = my_school.rooms
```

Now you want to find a list of articles based on their day attribute. A first step might be getting an array of uniq days. You can then pass that array to the where method. So you would have the following code in your controller:

```
days = some_rooms.map(&:day).uniq
@articles = Article.where(day: days)
```

This should give you what you are looking for. The active record query interface guide has a lot of useful things:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Brad Johnson. 
It would be appreciated if you could update how to write these code in my original controller and view code.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue you will not need to update your view. The first lines, the belong_to parts, need to be added to the models I specified in the answer. I updated my original answer to clarify that the last two lines will go in your controller. Would you mine accepting my answer?